# Seeding SecureRandom from user touch events in Android

Tags: java, android, random

I'm creating Android app that will generate securely random 256 bit keys. I would also like the user to have the option of generating random bytes from tapping / dragging on the screen that will seed the random number generator (kind of like how TrueCrypt generates its keys). It looks like `SecureRandom` is my best bet, but I'm having trouble understanding the `setSeed(byte[])` method.

Here is the documentation:

> Reseeds this random object. The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness.

I'm planning on taking the X and Y coordinates of the user's touch events and hashing them, then feeding the bytes from the hash repeatedly into `setSeed`.

My question is, will subsequent calls to `setSeed` strengthen the existing "randomness" or will it be more or less useless? Or is there a better way to achieve this that I'm completely missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "more or less useless".

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html):

> "any seed material passed to a SecureRandom object must be unpredictable", mouse movement probably does not meet that standard.

Generally CPRNGs continually add seeding from events on the device, you will not do better.

Also from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html):

> `void setSeed (long seed)`
>   Reseeds this random object, using the eight bytes contained in the given long seed. The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness.

So go ahead, you will do no harm but it is doubtful if you will improve anything.

Comment: There is an Android vulnerability regarding SecureRandom (before 4.2). On such devices adding extra seed may help but usually using `PRNGFixes` will be sufficient.

Comment: @Robert please provide a link to the vulnerability information.

Comment: @zaph: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html

Comment: @Robert Nice but does not provide information about the flaw, how severe, under what conditions and how the vulnerability is achieved. Please provide a link to the vulnerability information? BTW, any idea what percentage of Android devices are running pre-4.2?

Comment: @zaph: Seems like this vulnerability does not haven an CVE entry. According to Google currently about 9% have Android below 4.2: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards

Comment: What is interesting is if this an issue only under certain infrequent circumstances or a general issue for all usages of SecureRandom (before 4.2). Many vulnerabilities are only under very limited circumstances. One possible scenerio might be that it is vunerable ony soon after boot. That is important to know.